# Can a WIN32 program authenticate into Django authentication system, using MYSQL?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, django

I have a web service with Django Framework.
My friend's project is a WIN32 program and also a MS-sql server.

The Win32 program currently has a login system that talks to a MS-sql for authentication.

However, we would like to INTEGRATE this login system as one.

Please answer the 2 things:

1. I want scrap the MS-SQL to use only the Django authentication system on the linux server. Can the WIN32 client talk to Django using a Django API (login)?
2. If not, what is the best way of combining the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win32 client can act like a web client to pass the user's credentials to the server.  You will want to store the session cookie you get once you are authenticated and use that cookie in all following requests